# User registration form Wordpress shows Error： “NONCE ERROR,PLEASE RELOAD”

Tags: php, wordpress, user-registration

when my clients try to register on my site there is a "nonce error". I have checked this problem and most of them said it is a caching problem, I also tried to cancel the caching or deactivate the caching plugin, but it doesn't work.

They are happening lately in this one week before I never faced this problem.

I am using a WordPress website, using "USER Registration Form" for the registration, and "WP ROCKET" for caching. And I also have a Cloudflare account (I don't know if there is a problem with Cloudflare).

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the login and registration page in WP admin.